# Make ToC title look like report class in an article

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there any way to change the table of contents title in the article class to make it look like the report class?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{section1}
    \subsection{subsection1.1}  
    \subsection{subsection1.2}
\end{document}
```

I want my table of contents title to look as follows, both in size (chapter size) and text, like if it was generated using the report class.
[image]

Comment: `article` does not have `chapter`, so `chapter size` is not a really useful description

Comment: you want your sections numbered 0.1 not 1 ?

Comment: No, i want the title of the toc page to appear bigger, like in a report.

Answer (score 1):

`report` sets the ToC as a `\chapter*`. Here's a view of what `\chapter*` prints as the chapter header - it's done by the macro `\@makeschapterhead` which is specific to `s`tarred `chapter`s:

```
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

A space of `50pt` is set before the title, and `40pt` after the title. The title itself uses `\Huge\bfseries`. Here's this implementation for `article` using [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge\bfseries}% Similar to \chapter* in report
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{50pt}% Similar to \chapter* in report
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{40pt}% Similar to \chapter* in report

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{section1}
\subsection{subsection1.1}  
\subsection{subsection1.2}

\end{document}
```